# how can add the anchor tag title as URL and create as new page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can we add the anchor tag title as a url,
and this is work as a new web 
i redirect the urls in the global.asax
but this is not abjectly which i want

```
routes.MapPageRoute("-", "-", "~/Jobs/ShowResume.aspx");
```

ya we can try some more also

and an another page i am displaying some content using Datalist

```
   foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
            {
             if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Label lbldate = (Label)item.FindControl("lbldate");
                        string idate = lbldate.Text.Replace("/","-");
                        string date = TimeAgo(Convert.ToDateTime(idate));
                        lbldate.Text = date;
                        HyperLink hreflink = (HyperLink)item.FindControl("hreftitle");
                        hreflink.NavigateUrl = "../-?" + (hreflink.Text).ToString().Trim().Replace(" ", "-");                           

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {


                    }}
}
```

after doing this i getting a url 
http://localhost:55389/NXG-Alpha/-?S/w-In-a-Core-IT-Company

but i want http://localhost:55389/NXG-Alpha/S/w-In-a-Core-IT-Company

it is possible 
please suggest me some possible ways for solve it

Comment: What is in hreflink.Text?

Comment: Why are you adding "../-?" string in the URL?

Comment: hyperlink text is the control name of datalist

Comment: and i am using ../-? for calling a webpage and show the title of anchor tag in url

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to parse your date correctly.  I don't see where you are putting result of the date into the URL. So will assume that is not related to the Nav URL.

```
string dateString = "4/23/2015";
string controlName = "NXG-Alpha";
string controlSubDirectory = "S";
string controlPage = "w-In-a-Core-IT-Company";

// If we have a valid date
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dateTime))
{
    // Setup Navigation URL
    HyperLink hreflink = (HyperLink)item.FindControl("hreftitle");
    hreflink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("../{0}/{1}/{2}", controlName, controlSubDirectory, controlPage);
}
else
{ 
    // Date Error
    // TODO...
}
```